# VSCode intellisense doesn't detect Object type from JSDoc

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code, jsdoc

I'm using JSDoc in my project having both javascript and typescript, and I notice that in my js file if a parameter is defined as `Object` type then VSCode intellisense shows it as type `any`.

```
/**
 * @param {Object} options - 
 */
function testFunc(options) {
  return options;
}
```

[image: vscode intellisense Object]

If I use `object` then it seems to work fine.
[image: vscode intellisense object]

From what I've read [typescript handbook](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/jsdoc-supported-types.html#param-and-returns) and [jsdoc](https://jsdoc.app/tags-param.html) `Object` or `object` shouldn't make any difference, and I'm expecting vscode intellisense to show it properly as `object` type upon hover.

Furthermore, unlike other types, return type is not inferred automatically and it shows as `any` type.

Comment: What's the actual question?

Answer (score 2):

The `Object` is a typescript thing, when you pass `object` in lowercases, it considers the class `object` as existing. When you says the @param can take an `Object` in javascript, it's like saying it can take anything, because there is no difference. In TYPESCRIPT, the type `Object` is needed when you only want `Objects` and not `Numbers`, `Arrays` & `booleans`...